# Exporting default from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a file structure that looks like this

```
–Directory
--myComponent.js
––Subdirectory
–––fileA.js
–––fileB.js
–––index.js
––index.js
```

My **`Directory/Subdirectory/index.js`** looks like this:

```
export { default as fileA } from './fileA';
export { default as fileB } from './fileB';
```

My **`Directory/index.js`** looks like this:

```
export { default as myComponent } from './myComponent';
import * as _Subdirectory from './Subdirectory';
export const Subdirectory = _Subdirectory;
```

My question – can line 2 and 3 from **`Directory/index.js`** be written as a one-liner (just like line 1)?

Comment: Your exports should be imports ? do you have a typo there ? or is it just me

Comment: Nope - that's fine @ZohirSalak.

Comment: oh i didn't know you can export exports directly

Comment: No need to use `const`: `import * as Subdirectory from './Subdirectory'; export { Subdirectory }`. But no, it's always two statements, until [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from) is accepted.